# splash screen displayed once in phonegap app using cordova plugin

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, cordova

am creating one app on phone gap using cordova.
facing one problem is that splash screen, i want to show that splash screen only one time in my app. means when user install that app first time spalsh screen displayed but when second time user open that app splash screen is not displaying.

if anybody have solution of this problem then please share your code or idea.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

In config.xml you can specify the splash screen for cordova application.

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-splashscreen

Moreover, Splash screen plugin allows you to add functionality to your splash screen like when to hide splash screen and how many second splash screen should appear etc. So please take a look at the upper documentation.

Comment: For your spesific request you can use this approach: you can save a flag to to local storage of the device, according to the value of the flag which is coming from user's device local storage, you can show or hide splash screen by setting show time to 0 ms or N ms. In this way, if user first use the application, flag will be false and thats why you will show splash screen N ms, for other usage, flag will be true and according to flag value, you will show splash screen 0ms, which means splash screen will not be shown.